# How to use nuget packages and debug a source generator?

Tags: c#, nuget, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

So I wanted to try to write a source generator and found that I could debug them by using the `Roslyn component` debug profile.
My `launchSettings.json` look like this

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Debug": {
      "commandName": "DebugRoslynComponent",
      "targetProject": "..\\Test\\Test.csproj"
    }
  }
}
```

And when I press F5 everything works great my source generator works and I can add breakpoints.

But when I add a nuget package for example `Newtonsoft.Json` and try to use it I get `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`.

Just to clarify my source generator is using `Newtonsoft.Json` not the code it generates.

So I googled and found that you are supposed to add the following to the source generator

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
    <None Include="$(PkgNewtonsoft_Json)\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now when I create a nuget the `Newtonsoft.Json` is packaged inside the nuget like its supposed to be, but I sill get the error when I debug my generator, what am I missing?

I get the same error when I just try to build `Test.csproj`.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages

Edit:
I managed to get the debugging to work by adding `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to my `<PropertyGroup>`, but it does not work when just building a project that uses it.